# Access Control on DocumentDB Resources using R

Tags: c#, r, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to access Microsoft Azure DocumentDB with R, and I am having trouble generating the hashed token.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn783368.aspx

I have the master key, and from that I'd need to generate hashed key. Sample code is given in the link above for how to do that in C# or in JavaScript, but I am not sure how to do so in R. If you could point me to the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what R package are you using?

Answer (score 0):

here are some tips would do help.

1. [base64 {base64enc}](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/base64enc/docs/base64) :  Encode/decode data into/from base64 encoding
2. [string_to_sign](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/aws.signature/docs/string_to_sign): Construct a String To Sign with algorithm “AWS4-HMAC-SHA256”

You could search in [inside-R](http://www.inside-r.org/search/apachesolr_search?filters=) for more help.